# How can i remove the animate method from an element in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I am using the "animate" method on the nav element. Once the nav has been opened and a certain icon clicked, the animate method is then triggered to change the style of the nav. When i close the nav, i would like for the animation to be removed and return to it's default style used in the style sheet. Instead, some of the style from the animate's CSS parameter is not being cleared. How do i fix this?

```
$(".toggle").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $("nav").fadeToggle("medium");

});


$('.fa-heart-o').on("click", function(){

    //$('nav').addClass('animate');

    $('nav').animate({height:100,bottom:0}, 1000).addClass('animate');

    $('ul').addClass('clearfix');

});

$(".times").click(function(){

        $('nav').removeClass('animate').hide();

});
```

Comment: add a JSFiddle, please!

Comment: @JuaRoAl Test link: http://codecreatif.com/test_xyz/

Answer (score 0):

There may be lingering style changes to the object.  Inspect the element to see.  If so, you can change them to their default value (or the one you want them to be) with css('css-property', [default or desired value]);

Alternatively, if you don't want any of the lingering style="" effects, you can remove the whole thing with removeProp('style');

Comment: The default height value is set at 100%, jQuery doesn't allow the use of %  from my understanding.  Also in the jQuery specs, removeProp() is only for the use of removing properties set by the prop() method.

Comment: Then you can use removeAttr() instead.